# CodeIgniter Having Internal Server Error 500 when creating pdf file in tcpdf

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, pdf

I want to create a dynamic pdf file from database and so I tried different pdf extensions for php and I tried each of their sample tutorial to see if I can grasp the syntax but no matter what I do I always ending up with this error "POST (url) 500 (Internal Server Error). Please help because I will be using it for receipt printing. This is my class in library:

```
if(!defined('BASEPATH'))exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once APPPATH.'/libraries/tcpdf/tcpdf.php';

class Pdf extends TCPDF
{
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}
}
```

and this is the sample that I am writing following the tutorial:

```
    $pdf = new Pdf('P','mm','A4',true,'UTF_8',false);
    $pdf->SetTitle('PDF Example');
    $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(30);
    $pdf->setTopMargin(20);
    $pdf->setFooterMargin(20);
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true);
    $pdf->SetAuthor('Author');
    $pdf->SetDisplayMethod('real','default');
    $pdf->Write(5,'Codeigniter TCPDF Integration');
    $pdf->Output('pdfexample.pdf','I');
```

and this is the jquery trigger button for the printing:

```
$('#btnprint').click(function(){
var from = $('#datefrom').val();
var To = $('#dateTo').val();

$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: "<?php echo site_url('enrollment/printReceipt');?>",
data: {datefrom:from,dateTo:To},
success: function(data){
  console.log(data);
},
 });
});
```

I took the date values to see if the button calls the php script correctly..

This is my htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: do you have .htaccess file?

Comment: Yes I have a normal htaccess file

Comment: have you restricted something in htaccess

Comment: Please check my htaccess file...

Comment: htaccess looks great..500 error in browser network tab right ? manually hit url and check that happening ?

Comment: what do you mean by manually hitting the url?

Comment: domain.com/enrollment/printReceipt hit in browser and check

Comment: I type this "http://localhost/enrollment/index.php/enrollment/printReceipt" and got the call to undefined function SetDisplayMethod error...

Comment: Sorry I type it wrong instead of SetDisplayMode I type SetDisplayMethod but after I corrected it I have been receiving "TCPDF ERROR: </strong>Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file"

Comment: Ok thanks I solved it I just need to put ob_end_clean before the output call...